# Seeking computer-based family-tree software for Mac/PC?

Tags: software-recommendations, family-tree

I am looking for a software program that works cross platform Mac/PC and isn’t exclusively cloud-based. Also I want to have access to my own data, so Ancestry software, though nice, doesn’t tick any boxes.

Plus, I want to upload and tag photos, documents, and notes.

The Master Genealogist met my requirements but is no longer supported.

Answer (score 3):

There are several programs that should meet your needs.  The one I'm familiar with is [**Family Tree Maker**](https://www.mackiev.com/ftm/).

I have used it on the Mac for years.  It had a separately done PC version.  The company that made the PC version decided to stop and now the same company does both.

All your data resides on your computer.  You can choose whether or not you wish to sync FTM with Ancestry.com (it does both directions).  It works perfectly without any internet connection at all.

You can upload photos, documents, etc.  Notes function is built in.

The one element you mention that I don't believe it does is to allow you to tag photos/etc.  But you can link them to multiple profiles and look up that list.

Most importantly, you buy it once and you have it forever.  Of course, if you upgrade your computer or its operating system, you may need to purchase an upgrade of the software, but you never have to purchase a subscription of any kind.